# How accurate is the ApproximateReceiveCount from SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a system where multiple workers consume from a standard SQS queue in parallel.

I noticed that when I have a relatively large number of messages (i.e. 3 millions), my total processed count at the end always result in a few more messages (around 30) than the total number of messages. (0.001% ~ 0.002% more)

I suspect it is because of the "At-least-once" delivery:

> Amazon Doc: It is possible you will receive a message even after you have deleted it. This might happen on rare occasions if one of the servers storing a copy of the message is unavailable when you request to delete the message. The copy remains on the server and might be returned to you again on a subsequent receive request. You should create your system to be idempotent so that receiving a particular message more than once is not a problem.

Therefore, I'd like to use "ApproximateReceiveCount" to determine if my message has been processed before processing it:

```
(Worker pseudocode)

List messages = sqs.receiveMessage()
for m in messages:
   if m.approximateReceiveCount > 1 then
      skip process
   else
      process as usual
end
```

I'm wondering how accurate is this "approximateReceiveCount" and whether it is a good idea to have my de-duplication logic depend on it.

Note that:

I have setup a Dead Letter queue to handle any message that took longer than "Default Visibility Timeout" (set to 1h). Since no message was put back to the Dead Letter, I assume that the extra counts are not due to this "timeout" effet.

Comment: It's not accurate enough to base your de-dupe logic on it. That's why it is called "approximate". Your best bet for de-dupe logic is to check the SQS message ID against something like a DynamoDB table with strongly consistent reads and conditional writes.

Comment: Exceeding the visibility timeout does toss the message to DLQ but only if the last time that happens, the message exceeds the number of receives configured with the DLQ settings.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot max receive set to 1

Comment: If you receive a message, and don't delete it, it should appear in the DLQ once the visibility timeout expires.

Comment: I have a theory: 
Is it possible that when your consumers do get the **same message** twice, they also get the **same approximateReceiveCount**?   
If so, that's the way to find and discard duplicates

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot reliably use the `approximateReceiveCount` property to de-duplicate messages. Because if you receive a message, then fail, your `approximateReceiveCount` could be 1, but the message still needs to be processed again.

When working with SQS, best practice is to ensure your SQS message processing is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). Meaning that processing the same message multiple times will yield the same results.

What this means exactly depends on your business logic.

1. You could track the SQS message IDs to determine if they have been processed already.
2. Or you could have some other ID within the message that determines whether the message has been processed already.
3. Or you could process the data multiple times, each time reaching the same result.

Solution 1 or 2 could be hard to reliably implement due to possible race conditions between processing, tracking, and possible failure.

Solution 3 may be best because you may not be able to do 1 or 2 transactually in case of a processing failure.

**Issues with solutions 1 or 2**

Example 1:

Suppose your logic is as follows:

1. Receive message from queue
2. Process message
3. Record message for de-duplication
4. Delete message from queue

However, if you fail between steps 2 and 3, or the message is received a second time by another processor between steps 2 and 3, then your de-duplication logic has failed.

Example 2:

Alternatively, suppose your logic is as follows:

1. Receive message from queue
2. Record message for de-duplication
3. Process message
4. Delete message from queue

Now, if you fail after step 2, or during step 3 (meaning processing never completes correctly), then you will never get another proper processing of your message.

Comment: Idempotent, indeed, is the only genuinely correct answer.  A FIFO queue has better protections in place to prevent some mishandling of messages *if (in some cases) you actually use them*, including errors during receive which could otherwise cause the receive count to be > 1 when you have never actually seen the message, but even then this answer is still fundamentally correct.

Comment: I have a theory: Is it possible that when your consumers do get the **same message** twice, they also get the **same approximateReceiveCount**? If so, that's the way to find and discard duplicates

Comment: Probably a better way to process jobs from SQS: when you are processing the message, start a thread to continuously increase the visibility timeout of the message and when you are done processing, delete the message. If you encounter an exception while processing the message then decide whether to delete the message or make it visible again in the queue, if you delete it means you don't want to retry. In this way you may process the message again but it will be an intentional retry.